"this" is not avaible in the current context with EventCallback.Factory.Create
Here is my code:
private readonly Dictionary<string, ComponentMetadata> components = new()
    {
        [nameof(ChoiceOfAnswerQuestion)] = new ComponentMetadata()
        {
            Type = typeof(ChoiceOfAnswerQuestion),
            Name = "Choix multiple",
            Parameters = {
                { nameof(ChoiceOfAnswerQuestion.OnValidSubmit), EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, HandleValidSubmit) },
                { nameof(ChoiceOfAnswerQuestion.OnCancel), EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, CancelEdit) }
            }
        },
        [nameof(AssociationQuestion)] = new ComponentMetadata()
        {
            Type = typeof(AssociationQuestion),
            Name = "Association",
            Parameters = {
                { nameof(AssociationQuestion.OnValidSubmit), EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, HandleValidSubmit) },
                { nameof(AssociationQuestion.OnCancel), EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, CancelEdit) }
            }
        }
    };

...
private async Task DeleteQuestion(int questionId)
{
    ...
}

...
private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    ...
}

The error occurs at "this". I don't know why but it doesn't take the "this". This is the complete message:

Keywork 'this' is not available in the current context

It should works, because my callback doesn't has argument and I should not pass any return type to the create because the functions are Task.
By the way, I've followed the EventCallBack section here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Maybe you can help me?

Unlike the example code linked, you're using this a field initializer, not a property getter.
